# SSAS - MSBI - Solution - Suggestions

Tags: ssas, startup, solution

Is it correct in my understanding that we can build SSAS cubes sourcing from the transaction Systems? I meant the not the live but copy of the Live.

I'm trying to see if there is any scope to address few reporting needs without the need to build a traditional Data Warehouse and then build cubes on top of the data warehouse, instead build cubes to do Financial monthly aggregated reporting needs sourcing from backup copy of the Transaction systems.

Alternatively, if you have any better way to proceed please suggest.

Regards,
KK

Answer (score 1):

You can create a set of views on top of you transactional system tables and then build your SSAS cubes ontop of those views. This would be less effort than creating a fully fledged datawarehouse.

Comment: Is there any advantage in building a views above the transactional system? Just to let you know transactional system is not used by anyone. Its a daily copy of the live system.

Comment: Having a series of views between your source / cube provide a useful interface layer to aid with data restricting, field naming, security and masking the cube from source system changes.  The small cost of implementing is far outweighed by their long term benefits.

Answer (score 1):

I am a data warehouse developer (and therefore believe in cubes), but not every reporting solution warrants the cost of building a cube.  If your short to medium term reporting requirements are fixed and you don't have users requiring data to be sliced differently each week, then a series of fixed reports may suffice.

You can create a series of SQL Server Reporting Services reports (or extract to Excel) either directly against your copied transactional data, or against a series of summarised tables that are created periodically.  If you decide to utilise a series of pre-formatted reporting tables, try to create tables that cover multiple similar reports (rather than 1 monthly report table = 1 report) for ease of ongoing maintenance.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Myself coming from traditional data warehouse developer believe in building ODS>>DWH>>Report>>Cubes. But due to short time to deliver few Summarized reports I was trying to draw a solution on paper to build cubes. I liked your second paragraph solution. This might workout for this case. In longer term do you think the traditional approach gives more benefits and is a right approach?

Comment: I would not advise replacing a working reporting system with a cube just for the sake of it.  There are benefits, but only if your consumer is going to make use of benefits a cube delivers (query performance through aggregation, calc measures, security, ad-hoc queries through front-end tools, date-time comparisons etc).  Sometimes a cube can be a sledgehammer to crack a nut...

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable inputs. The final solution to address the current reporting solution is to consider the current backup copies as the ODS and build a data Warehouse. By taking this approach the current reporting system is still intact and a new solution in parallel will be in process. Going forward, new reports to be build on the data warehouse.Slowly decommission the existing reports accessing the backup copies. Interesting thing which I found recently was there is MI reporting on live source systems. Hence, the data warehouse approach. Daryl - Am I on right track?

Comment: Sounds like a sensible plan to build up from what is already in place.  Good luck msbikk

Answer (score 0):

There are many other important aspects to this that you may need to consider first. Like how busy is the transaction system, what is the size of the data, concurrency and availability issues etc.

It is absolutely fine to have a copy of your live data and then build a report on the top of it. Bear in mind that the data you see in the report will not be the latest and there will be a latency factor depending on the frequency of your data pull.